# Identify SMD voltage regulator with top marking: T1A30

Tags: voltage-regulator, identification

I have a circuit powered by a 3.3 V regulator. The regulator is a SMD one, with this marking on its surface T1A30:

I am in need of a comprehensive identification and description of the SMD voltage regulator with the code "T1A30," which is utilized as a power supply element in my circuit. Specifically, I seek information about its manufacturer, specifications, pinout, and any relevant datasheets that provide technical details.

I've a circuit powered by a 3.3 V regulator. The regulator is a SMD one, with this logo and code on its surface:

Drawing of top marking and logo

footprint is SOT23-3 or very similar.

I need to know the information about this voltage regulator. Unfortunately, I do not find any information about this marking code.

Any hint about how to continue?

The pinout is:

[image]

Comment: I’m not sure which IC this is, but maybe you could try replacing it with a pin-compatible IC with the same functionality and input/output voltage range? Something like the LP3992IMFX-1.5/NOPB assuming those are the output voltages that you need and the output current would be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you I think you are right, will give it a try.

Comment: Is that possible to provide a better quality image? And can you confirm that the package dimension is SOT-23-5 ?

Answer (score 0):

That could be a [R3134N33EC](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/792/r3134-ec-911524.pdf) from RICOH. (now [Nisshinbo](https://www.nisshinbo-microdevices.co.jp/en/pdf/datasheet/r3134-ea.pdf))
Significant code would be T1A.
Unfortunately I didn't find any picture.

[image]
[image]